# Python/CSV Read Data

Tags: python

My program shown below has the goal of outputting statements based off two criteria:(`Year` and `Location`) Once that was accomplished, my next goal is to match `year` with `Yearlink` and `Location` with `location`. `location` and `year` are both input statements. The output should be a statement that outputs values from that row. For some reason, I always receive an error about too many values to unpack. Also when I fix that error, it never outputs anything for that section of the program. The first part of program is outputting correctly. Second part is either giving me Value Error or not outputting at all. My excel sheet is posted if anyone wants a better idea of what I am talking about.[image: Excel Sheet] Anyway I tried everything but nothing was working for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/RoszkowskiM/Desktop/win4.py", line 134, in <module>
for From,To,Max,Min in data:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

-

```
LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\Data_2016.csv' # CSV File to Read
    # read the entire CSV into Python.
    # CSV has columns starting with Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,location
    data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
    mydict = {}
    for row in data:
        Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,Location,Yearlink,From,To,Max,Min = row[0:12]



    #If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
    if Year not in mydict:
        mydict[Year] = {}

    busses_in_year = mydict[Year]
    if Location not in busses_in_year:
         busses_in_year[Location] = []


    #Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
    busses_in_year[Location].append((busnum,busname,scaled_power))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#User Input Statement
year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ")
print("\n")

commands = ["Millwood-Buchanan", "Astoria-East-Corona", "Bronx", "DUNWOODIE-North-Sherman_Creek",
            "Vernon", "Greenwood-StatenIsland","West_49th","East_13th","Staten_Island","East_River",
            "East_View","DUNWOODIE-SOUTH","Corona-Jamaica","Astoria-East-Corona-Jamaica",
            "Astoria-West-Queensbridge-Vernon","Astoria-West-Queensbridge"]
max_columns = 50

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print(row)
location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")
print("\n")
Year=year
Location=location




if Year in mydict and Location in mydict[Year]:  
    busses_in_year = mydict[Year]
    print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
    print("\n")


#Busnum, busname,scaled_power read from excel sheet matching year and location

for busnum,busname,scaled_power in busses_in_year[Location]:
    scaled_power= float(scaled_power)
    busnum = int(busnum)
    print('Bus #: %d\t' % busnum ,'Area Station: %s\t'% busname,'New Load Total: %d MW\t' % scaled_power)
else:
        exit
```

-

```
 for row in data:
    Year,busnum,busname,scaled_power,tla,Location,Yearlink,From,To,Max,Min = row[0:11]

    if Yearlink==year and Location==location:
            for From,To,Max,Min in data:
                From=int(From)
                To=int(To)
                Max=float(Max)
                Min=float(Min)
                print('From Bus #: %d\t' % From ,'To Bus #: %d\t'% To,'VMAX: %d pu\t' % Max, 'VMIN: %d pu\t' % Min)                                                                

else:                                                                                                               
    exit
```

Comment: please add your data sample as plain text

Comment: Too many values to unpack implies that data (or another tuple/list value) has more values inside of it than the values it is being assigned to.  It seems like  'for From,To,Max,Min in data', data has more than 4 values. I'd suggest you assign it as 'for i in data' and print i to see what's up.

Comment: You might want to consider using pandas for reading sections of CSV

Comment: @Landmaster Actually, that whole line is wrong. `data` is already being iterated a few lines above, and `From`, `To`, `Max` and `Min` are being unpacked from `row`.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `data` to get the `row`s, but then you iterate again over `data` to get `From`, `To`, `Max` and `Min`, which you had already unpacked. That line doesn't make sense. This should work:

```
for row in data:
    data_location, year_link, from_, to, max_value, min_value = row[5:11]
    output = 'From Bus #: {}\tTo Bus #: {}\tVMAX: {} pu\tVMIN: {} pu\t'
    if year_link == year and data_location == location:
        print(output.format(from_, to, max_value, min_value))
```

I simplified a bit and changed the variable names, but the only thing you have to do is remove that spurious `for` line.

Comment: @ Paulo Almeida I keep getting a `ValueError: Need More Than 5 Values to Unpack`

Comment: @Mark The slice was wrong, it was supposed to be `row[5:11]`, I corrected it.